# How do I return #N/A from a custom function using the Excel Javascript API?

Tags: excel, office-js

I want to return the error value `#N/A` from a custom function using the Excel JS API. I can't find a way to do this. Can anyone point me to the right function?

Comment: Return the result of the [`NA()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheet-functions#supported-worksheet-functions)?

Comment: Yes, I want to return the result of the NA() function from my custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is now possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-errors

Answer (score 0):

currently this is not possible. But good news is that we're working on it.  Stay tuned to the github repo, specifically this tracking item here:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions/issues/149

Can you describe your scenario for reference? Want to make sure it will fit your needs. Is it just NA or do you need to return other errors? In what case do you return #NA?

thanks!

Comment: I'm doing a data lookup in my custom function and in case of non-existence I want to return NA(), so that dependent cells are not evaluated.

Comment: Cool! If you are also interested in joining some of weekly  excel addin calls, let me know - kepatel@microsoft.com